# ¿Por qué la matriz de confusión siempre sale de esta forma?

Tags: python, keras

EStoy entrenando un modelo de red neuronal convolucional, pero siempre la matriz de confusión me sale de la misma forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque no siempre se acumulan todos los datos en la primera columna, tambien puede pasar con cualquiera de las demas, pero siempre aparecen los datos acumulados en una columna.

Las clases están desbalanceadas, para ello, he probado diferentes métodos en el fit generator:

```
weight_dict={
    0:1-0.73636,
    1:1-0.069197,
    2:1-0.15062,
    3:1-0.02437,
    4:1-0.01943
}

class_weights1 = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                 np.unique(validation_generator.classes),
                                                 validation_generator.classes)

counter = Counter(train_generator.classes)
max_val = float(max(counter.values()))
class_weights2 = {class_id : max_val/num_images for class_id, num_images in counter.items()}
```

Yo pienso que esto es algo que tiene que ver justamente con el desbalanceo de clases. Os ha pasado alguna vez algo así? Sabeis cual puede ser el motivo?

Comment: [No deberías forzar una etiqueta en el título](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2464/qu%c3%a9-significa-no-deber%c3%adas-forzar-una-etiqueta-en-el-t%c3%adtulo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que tu red neuronal, solo predice una clase, por ello en la matriz de confusión te salen todos los datos en una columna. En este ejemplo, tu red neuronal predice que todos los datos pertenecen a la **clase 1**.

Esto sucede cuando tu red neuronal no es capaz de aprender e identificar patrones que diferencien unas clases de otras.

Los motivos por los que pueden pasar son muy diversos, y se necesitaría un análisis completo y largo del problema. Algunos pueden ser:

- Falta de datos: las redes neuronales necesitan miles y miles de datos para aprender patrones correctamente.
- Estructura de la red neuronal demasiado simple/compleja.
- Clases desbalanceadas.
- Parametros de la red neuronal mal configurados...
- Falta de tratamiento y limpieza inicial de los datos.

etc..

Comment: Y eso por que motivo puede pasar? como se puede solucionar?

Comment: Es complicado de saber, habría que hacer un análisis complejo de los datos y la situación por completo, Te he editado la respuesta y te he puesto algunos

Comment: Sabia que podia estar encaminado por las clases desbalanceadas, he probado los métodos que puse en mi pregunta, pero no funciona ninguno